# UITableView's Items Change Color After Scrolling Down, Then Back Up Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making an iOS app with swift and Xcode 11. Inside my app, there is a scrollable table view controller, consisting of buttons on the left and right side, like this:

[image]

These are 2 of the many UITableViewCells that I've made. When the user presses the red button, the once red button becomes green. But there's a glitch: If I press a red button(button goes green) and then I scroll down inside the UITableView(and scroll back up), the button that was once green(and still should be green) isn't green anymore. I have no idea why this is happening and I've scrounged StackOverflow's other similar questions like this one, but did not manage to find any.

Here's my UITableViewController:

```swift
import UIKit

@objcMembers class CustomViewController: UITableViewController {

    var tag = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tag = 0
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        tag = 0
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return SingletonViewController.themes.count
    }



    // 3
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        tag = tag + 1

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "themeCell", for: indexPath) as! ThemeCell


            let cellButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: 88, height: 119.5))
            cellButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cell.addSubview(cellButton)
            cell.accessoryView = cellButton
            cellButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            cellButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            cellButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 88).isActive = true
            cellButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 119.5).isActive = true
        cellButton.setImage(UIImage(named: SingletonViewController.themes[indexPath.row]), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            cellButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomViewController.backBTN(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            cellButton.tag = tag

        var cellyi: UIButton!

//red/green button's declaration^
        cellyi = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 50, height: 30))
        cell.addSubview(cellyi)
        cell.accessoryView = cellyi
        cellyi.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        cellyi.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomViewController.backBTN(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cellyi.tag = tag

        print(cellyi.tag)

        if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "like") == 0{
            UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "like")
        }

        if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "like") == tag{
            cellyi.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }

        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        return cell
    }

    @objc func backBTN(sender: UIButton){
        UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.tag, forKey: "like")

        tag = 0
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Comment: The short answer is cells are reused as you scroll. You shouldn't add views/buttons in `cellForRow`; they should be in your cell subclass. Also, adding 1 to the `tag` property isn't going to work as `cellForRow` will be called multiple times for the same cell and not necessarily in row order.  You should save the indexPath.row to track your selection.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks that solved it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The `cellForRowAt` method is not a for loop!**

I see that you are using a `tag` property to control what gets shown in each cell. From the fact that you increment the `tag` very time `cellForRowAt` is called, you seem to assume that `cellForRowAt` will be called once for each row, in order. **This is not the case, and you should not implement `cellForRowAt` like this.**

`cellForRowAt` essentially asks a question: "What should the cell at this index path be?", and you provide the answer. The index path that the table view is asking about is the `indexPath` parameter. You should make use of this parameter instead of your own `tag` property, because the table view is not asking about that.

The reason why why your code doesn't work is because table view cells are reused. When cells are scrolled out of view, they are not put aside, so that when new table view cells need to be shown, they can be reconfigured to "appear as if they are new cells". Essentially what this means is that when you scroll up, `cellForRowAt` is called for the rows that are about to come into view. You didn't expect that, did you?

All that code that sets up each cell should be moved to the initialiser of `ThemeCell`. Alternatively, design the cell in a storyboard. `cellForRowAt` should only configure a cell specifically for an index path. `ThemeCell` should have the properties `cellButton` and `cellyi` so that the buttons can be accessed.

Now, `cellForRowAt` can be written like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "themeCell", for: indexPath) as! ThemeCell

    cell.cellButton.setImage(UIImage(named: SingletonViewController.themes[indexPath.row]), for: UIControl.State.normal)
    cell.cellButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomViewController.backBTN(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.cellyi.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomViewController.backBTN(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "like") == indexPath.row {
        cell.cellyi.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    } else {
        cell.cellyi.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    // this line should be moved to viewDidLoad
    // tableView.allowsSelection = false
    return cell
}
```

Comment: This is also where `prepareForReuse` is valuable as well. Being able to reset the state of the cell on each reuse to the default state (which I assume is `.red`) and then setting it `.green` on only when the condition is met.